# How can I make sure that every child is meeting one condition on Django Models?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I need to look for a recipe if and only if all of its ingredients are included in a list of ingredients.

In SQL the query would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM recipe r
WHERE no exists (SELECT 1
                   FROM recipe_ingredient ri
                  WHERE r.id = ri.recipe_id
                    AND ri.ingredient_id not in (1,2,3))
```

Where 1,2,3 is the list of ingredients.

How can I do this using Django Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your model looks like, but here is a possible approach

```
# Possible models.py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient', related_name='in_recipes')
    ...

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

# views.py
from django.db.models import Q

# Use Q objects to create a query that requires all ingredients
ingredient_query = None
for an_ingredient in REQUIRED_INGREDIENTS:
    ingredient_query = ingredient_query & Q(ingredients=an_ingredient) if ingredient_query else Q(ingredients=an_ingredient)

recipes_with_ingredients = Recipe.objects.filter(ingredient_query)
```